# tkinter concatenate entry name from string

Tags: python, tkinter

I have three entries like this:

```
e1 = Entry(master, state="readonly")
e2 = Entry(master, state="readonly")
e3 = Entry(master, state="readonly")
```

Is there any way to use a variable or string to define name of the `Entry` like:

```
x=int(1)
e+str(x) = Entry(master, state="readonly")
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can you dynamically create variables via a while loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5036700/how-can-you-dynamically-create-variables-via-a-while-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typical way to achieve this is by using a collection (here a list):

```
num_entries = 3
entries = []
for _ in range(num_entries):
    entries.append(Entry(master, state="readonly"))
```

The you can access each `Entry` object via its index, or iterate over all `entries`:

```
entries[0].get()
for entry in entries:
    entry.get()
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not use arrays and dictionnaries ?
Here's a sample that could help you :

```
vect = []
mas = #whatever object it is
st = 'readonly'
vect.append(({'master':mas},{'state':st}))
#Then you can read the elements of your array with
i = 0
vect[i] # where i is the index of the element you want (here there's only one
```

Which will print

> ({'master':#whats master}, {'state':'readonly'})